# Resizing the TimePicker in Universal Windows Platform

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

The TimePicker control in UWP doesn't re-size when properties like MaxWidth or Width are changed, is there another property I should set, or do I just have to find a work-around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, it seems you can only change the size of a TimePicker with the "Padding" property.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the default style of TimePicker. For example, please add the following style in your Page.Ressources. The only value I changed is MaxWidth to 800 - **the default one is 456**. You should then be able to maximize your control with Width property.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TimePicker -->
    <Style TargetType="TimePicker">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="242" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="800" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TimePicker">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style x:Key="TimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundAltMediumBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                                              BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"
                                                              Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltMediumLowBrush}"
                                                              BorderThickness="2"
                                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FirstColumnDivider"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SecondColumnDivider"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                      x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                                      Visibility="Collapsed"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                      Margin="0,0,0,8"
                                      Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" 
                                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                        <Button x:Name="FlyoutButton"
                            Style="{StaticResource TimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid x:Name="FlyoutButtonContentGrid">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="FirstTextBlockColumn" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="SecondTextBlockColumn" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="ThirdTextBlockColumn" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Border x:Name="FirstPickerHost" Grid.Column="0">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="HourTextBlock" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,3,0,5" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                </Border>

                                <Rectangle x:Name="FirstColumnDivider" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="2" Grid.Column="1" />

                                <Border x:Name="SecondPickerHost" Grid.Column="2">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="MinuteTextBlock" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,3,0,5" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                </Border>

                                <Rectangle x:Name="SecondColumnDivider" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="2" Grid.Column="3" />

                                <Border x:Name="ThirdPickerHost" Grid.Column="4">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="PeriodTextBlock" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,3,0,5" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Note. You can find all default styles in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic

Answer (score 2):

I found a very easy workaround for resizing the Timepicker or DatePicker. I just put a ViewBox around it and assign the width and height I want to the Viewbox. the Viewbox does all the sizing for the picker control for you. SImple. Done.

Comment: This was the only solution that seemed to work. And bonus points for being incredibly simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is different workarounds depending the target SDK of the project.

When the project targets to **Windows 10 1709 10.0.16299.0** setting the MinWidth property of the TimePicker is enough to reduce its width.

When the project targets to **Windows 10 1803 10.0.17763.0** replacing the default TimePickerThemeMinWidth value in the App.xaml file does the trick:

```
      <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
      <x:Double x:Key="TimePickerThemeMinWidth">140</x:Double>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
      <x:Double x:Key="TimePickerThemeMinWidth">140</x:Double>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
      <x:Double x:Key="TimePickerThemeMinWidth">140</x:Double>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```